# Maps from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ that preserve squeeze maps?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry

> What maps from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ preserve squeeze maps?

A squeeze map is a type of linear map that preserves Euclidean area regions of the Cartesian plane but is not a rotation or shear mapping.

For a fixed positive real number $a$ the mapping $(x,y)\mapsto (ax,y/a)$ is the squeeze mapping with parameter $a.$

So I'm looking to understand maps that preserve the structure of squeeze maps from $\Bbb R^2$ to itself. That is, if you have a squeeze map on $\Bbb R^2,$ what maps will preserve the squeeze map?

I have thought about this and come up with $3$ examples: $1)$ identity map, $2)$ involution map $3)$ any map that maps involutions to involutions.

Comment: Translations will preserve the squeeze but they aren't linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by "squeeze maps" you mean the $2$-dimensional manifold of symmetric positive-definite matrices $A$ of determinant $1$, which we will denote by $\mathcal{S}$.

You are asking for the set of all matrices $g \in \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$ g \mathcal{S} g^{-1} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$$.

Note that if $g \in O(2,\mathbb{R})$, then $g$ has the property above. Indeed, if $g$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $g^T g = I$, which implies that $g^{-1} = g^T$. Hence

$$ g \mathcal{S} g^{-1} = g \mathcal{S} g^T \subseteq \mathcal{S}.$$

To see why this is so, note that if $A \in \mathcal{S}$, then $gAg^{-1} = gAg^T$ is symmetric. Note also that

$$(gAg^{-1}v, v) = (A g^{-1}v, g^T v) = (A g^{-1}v, g^{-1}v) > 0,$$

for all nonzero $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Moreover, $\operatorname{det}(gAg^{-1}) = \operatorname{det}(A) = 1$.

Moreover, if $g = \lambda I$, for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lambda \neq 0$, then also $g$ has the property we seek.

In short, if $g \in CO(2,\mathbb{R})$ (the conformal group in dimension $2$), then $g$ has the property the OP is interested in.

Now, let us assume that $k \in \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$ k \mathcal{S} k^{-1} \subset \mathcal{S}.$$

Then what can we say about $k$? I think, but I am not sure, that $k \in CO(2, \mathbb{R})$. I will have to think a bit more about it though...

Edit: indeed, my last claim is true. I proved it by taking two special classes for $A$. By taking $A \in \mathcal{S}$ to be diagonal, imposing the condition we are interested in leads to the two columns of $A$ being orthogonal. However, the two columns may, a priori, have $2$ different norms. And then, by taking $A \in \mathcal{S}$ to have $1$s on the diagonal, and after imposing again the condition above, one gets that $k \in CO(2,\mathbb{R})$.

More explicitly, $CO(2,\mathbb{R})$ consists of matrices $g$ of the form

$$ g = \left( \begin{array}{cc} u & -v \\ v & u \end{array} \right),$$

where $u$ and $v$ are real numbers which are not both $0$. Note that $CO(2, \mathbb{R})$ includes for example rotations, reflections and scaling (it is actually generated by these $3$ types of linear transformations).